# how to bind variable value in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to display some **variable value** in **gridview**.

**Code:**

```
 int cnt = Convert.ToInt32(txtCount.Text);
 DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
 DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);
 TimeSpan datedifference = end.Subtract(start);
 int dateCount = datedifference.Days;
 float maxUpload = dateCount * 288;  
 float remainingUpload = maxUpload - cnt;
 float averageUpload = remainingUpload / (dateCount * 288) * 100;
```

I want show the value of **dateCount**, **maxUpload**,**remainingUpload** and **averageUpload** in a gridview. Please help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Comment: So your `Gridview` will have only 1 row?

Comment: @Reshma if only one row than why you want to use gridview? just create html table and place four label in td of html table

Comment: @Sandeep : Now I am done like you said, but I need to show in grid.

Comment: @Reshma any reason from using grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your variables to a `multi-dimensional array`.
And then bind that array to a `DataTable`.

**Code**

```
int cnt = Convert.ToInt32(txtCount.Text);
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);
TimeSpan datedifference = end.Subtract(start);
int dateCount = datedifference.Days;
float maxUpload = dateCount * 288;  
float remainingUpload = maxUpload - cnt;
float averageUpload = remainingUpload / (dateCount * 288) * 100;

string[,] row1 = { { dateCount.ToString(), maxUpload.ToString(), remainingUpload .ToString(), averageUpload .ToString() } };

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("DateCount", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("maxUpload", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("remainingUpload", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("averageUpload", typeof(string));
for (int i = 0; i <= row1.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    table.Rows.Add();
    table.Rows[i]["DateCount"] = row1[i, 0];
    table.Rows[i]["maxUpload"] = row1[i, 1];
    table.Rows[i]["remainingUpload"] = row1[i, 2];
    table.Rows[i]["averageUpload"] = row1[i, 3];
}

gridview1.DataSource = table;
gridview1.DataBind();
```

**Source Code**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">

</asp:GridView>
```

And don't forget to add this `namespace` also.

```
using System.Data;
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateCount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# dateCount %>
//Your Public Scope Variable Goes Here
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a data table then set header to the grid view then using gridview.Add method add values to grid view.then set the data source to grid-view at last bind values with gridview

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("header1"), new DataColumn("header2 "), new DataColumn("header3") });
            dt.Rows.Add(cnt , start , end );

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

[How add values of columns of gridview in asp.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/353473/How-add-values-of-columns-of-gridview-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display only one row than you can use label and html table:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th>Max Upload</th>
            <th>Remaining Upload</th>
            <th>Average Upload</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMaxUpload" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRemainingUpload" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAverageUpload" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

int cnt = Convert.ToInt32(txtCount.Text);
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStart.Text);
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEnd.Text);
TimeSpan datedifference = end.Subtract(start);
int dateCount = datedifference.Days;
float maxUpload = dateCount * 288;  
float remainingUpload = maxUpload - cnt;
float averageUpload = remainingUpload / (dateCount * 288) * 100;

lblCount.Text = Convert.ToString(dateCount);
lblMaxUpload.Text = Convert.ToString(maxUpload );
lblRemainingUpload.Text = Convert.ToString(remainingUpload );
lblAverageUpload.Text = Convert.ToString(averageUpload );
```